# Prove: $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove: $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$

I tried it like this:

Let $S\in \mathcal P(A\cap B)\implies S\subseteq A\cap B\implies S\subseteq A$ and $S\subseteq B\implies S\in \mathcal P(A)$ and $S\in \mathcal P(B)\implies$
$$\mathcal P(A\cap B) = \mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$$

Can someone tell me if my proof is correct? and also I have a couple more questions on this topic:

What is the first approach, the first intuitive thought that you have when you need to prove something like this? For example what if the exercise was: $$\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)\subseteq\mathcal P(A\cup B)$$
What do you think about when you have this? Can someone explain me this in more detail and maybe using an example?

Comment: That looks like a proof of $P(A\cap B)\subseteq P(A)\cap P(B)$.

Comment: That's only half the proof. You also need to prove the implication the other way.

Comment: Why was this question marked down? I don't see how it doesn't comply with the community guidelines? what have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

For a two-way proof of the first claim write $$x\in\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)\iff x\subseteq A\cap B\iff x\subseteq A\land x\subseteq B\iff x\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B).$$(The approach you've already taken can flesh out the steps a little more, but the point is we can write the steps so each new statement is equivalent to the previous one, proving to directions at once.) For the second claim just replace every $\cap,\,\land$ with $\cup,\,\lor$. This works because of [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).