# Evaluating the claims $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$ and $\mathcal P(A\cup B)=\mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So at my Discrete Mathematics class , The Professor gave us two questions to prove/disprove each , he then proceeded to prove the first and disprove the 2nd by counter example , However if I applied the rules from the first problem on the second , I could "prove" it even though it's wrong , So here's the picture can anyone tell me what went wrong ?

[2 Problems](https://imgur.com/a/brATpA3)

---

Transcription of the image:

## Left column:

1) $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B)=\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$

$\text { Let } x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \therefore X \subseteq A \cap B$

$x \subseteq A \wedge x \subseteq B$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(A)\wedge x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$

$\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \wedge \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow(1)$

$\text { Let } x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$

$x \subseteq A \wedge x \subseteq B$

$x \subseteq A \cap B$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$

$\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \rightarrow(2)$

From (1),(2) $\quad \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)=\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$

## Right column:

2) $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)=\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$

Let $x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)\therefore x \subseteq A \cup B$

$x \subseteq A\vee x \subseteq B$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(A)\vee x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$

$\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow(3)$

Let $x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$

$x \in A \vee x \subseteq B$

$x \subseteq A \cup B$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$

$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) \rightarrow(4)$

$\text{From}(3),(4)=\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)=\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$

## Finally below the columns:

Disproving
2) $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)=\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$

$\text{Let }A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}, A \cup B=\{1,2\}$

$\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}, \mathcal{P}(B)=\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}$

$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\}\}, \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

Comment: I understand at first glance this question appears to be poorly formatted. However, a glance at the image link will show you what a challenge it would be to format everything.  Given the context in the image and the apparent misunderstanding visible, I think this question deserves to stay around.

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathcal%20P(A%5Ccap%20B)%3D%5Cmathcal%20P(A)%5Ccap%20%5Cmathcal%20P(B)%24&p=1) you can find some older related posts: [Intuition: Power Set of Intersection/Union (Velleman P77 & Ex 2.3.10, 11)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499746), [Prove: $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076691) or [Prove that $\mathcal P(A \cap B)=\mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P (B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987989).

Comment: The image has now been transcribed (using mathpix it wasn't too hard.)

Answer (score 3):

From $X\subseteq A\cup B$ it does not follow that $X\subseteq A$ or $A\subseteq B$.

Consider $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$ and $X=A\cup B$.  $X$ is a subset of $A\cup B$, and yet not a subset of either $A$ or $B$.

So, literally the second line of the right hand side is already an incorrect deduction.  What follows, therefore, is not acceptable.

> Can I use the right steps to prove something and still get the wrong proof?

Of course, a proof wouldn't be a proof if you could use a series of valid steps led to something wrong.  What seems to have happened is that you "dualized" the proof by swapping ands with ors and thought it must still be all "right steps."

It is simply not true that you can “dualize” every argument and get a valid proof. That only works under certain conditions.  The current situation is a great example.

Comment: Downvoter: Well, ok I'll bite... what seems to be worth downvoting? This is where they went wrong...